# How do I set a background to the lower portion of screen? CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making this... "game". Currently, it's a little stickman that walks around. There's also a tree. But that doesn't matter for now. I'm trying to set a background to the lower part of the screen. I've looked around and I can't seem to find an answer.

I've tried to set DIV wrappers, but I already have one to make the background blue. Also, if I'd make a div wrapper, I can't just select the lower portion of the screen. I know that I could do something like this

```
div#wrapper {
    margin-top: 700px;
    background-image: url('terrain blah blah blah');
}
```

but that doesn't work, because it applies "margin" to every other thing with it. Since the div wrapper wraps the whole page.

Here's the link: http://www.dotcomaftereverything.com/jquery/game.
As you can see, the whole page is blue. Because of the sky's color.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

**I can't use margin-top, because the wrapper wraps the whole page, therefore taking everything else down with it.. Which results in a blank page.**

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be a possible soultion.

You already have a `#terrain` element into your page, so just wrap the part of HTML code relative to the game into a sub-container, add some CSS and you're done.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>Life of an unlucky person</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery-rotate.googlecode.com/files/jquery.rotate.1-1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='wrapper'>
            <div id="playarea">
                <p>Left/Right arrow keys to move, space to sit down.</p><br />
                <img src='http://www.dotcomaftereverything.com/jquery/sprites/spritePerson.png' id='img' />
                <img id='sitting' src='http://www.dotcomaftereverything.com/jquery/sprites/spriteSitting.png' />
                <img id='tree' src='http://www.dotcomaftereverything.com/jquery/sprites/spriteTree.png' />
            </div>
            <div id='terrain'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#playarea {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}

    #playarea p {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #img {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 375px;
    }

    #sitting {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 375px;
    }

    #tree {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 700px;
    }

#terrain {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    var playarea = $('#playarea'),
        terrain = $('#terrain'),
        pageHeight = $(window).height(),
        areaHeight = playarea.height();
    terrain.css('height', (pageHeight - areaHeight) + 'px');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var sitting = $('#sitting'),
        image = $('#img');
    sitting.hide();
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
            arrow = {
                left: 37,
                up: 38,
                right: 39,
                down: 40,
                space: 32
            };
        switch (keyCode) {
            case arrow.left:
                if (!sitting.is(':visible')) {
                    image.add(sitting).stop(true).animate({
                        left: '-=60px'
                    }, 300, "linear");
                }
                break;
            case arrow.up:
                break;
            case arrow.right:
                if (!sitting.is(':visible')) {
                    image.add(sitting).stop(true).animate({
                        left: '+=60px'
                    }, 300, "linear");
                }
                break;
            case arrow.down:
                break;
            case arrow.space:
                image.fadeToggle(-100, function () {
                    sitting.fadeToggle(-100);
                });
                break;
        }
    });
    $('#sit').click(function () {});
});
```

Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/amekuy/3/edit)

Comment: Uhh, strangely, it doesn't display the terrain. Check the live example

Comment: Yep. I'm checking why this does happens in live and doesn't in code view.

Comment: Nope. I'm still figuring out why the result is different through the views.

Comment: That's really strange... It's probably some kind of CSS bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in position, repeat and attachment

```
div#wrapper {
margin-top: 700px;
background-image: url('terrain blah blah blah');
background-position:bottom left;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Comment: I **can't** use margin-top 700px because it drags the whole page down with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
div#wrapper {
    margin-top: 700px;
    background: url('terrain blah blah blah') bottom center repeat-x fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't setting the absolute position to 0 on bottom solve your problem?

```
<img src="http://img.wallpaperstock.net:81/floating-land-wallpapers_9536_1280x1024.jpg" style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;">
```